# Jumping the selection of value by 3 regardless of the id name

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the values using query `` SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `cid` ASC LIMIT 3 ``

But what happens is id don’t seem to get it to retrieve from 5 to 7, 8 to 9 or 10 to 12. I CANNOT USE the query `` WHERE `time` = 5 `` or something since the values from cid constantly changing. Can this be done? just jumping the retrieval of values by 3?

[image]

Comment: `LIMIT offset, count`, e.g `LIMIT 6,3`

Comment: However, if someone deletes cid = 3 after you've read 1 to 3, you will never read cid = 5.

Comment: @jarlh mind blown! it solves the problem! awsome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LIMIT` has an offset option as well: `LIMIT offset, count`, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `cid` ASC LIMIT 6, 3
```

However, if someone deletes the row with cid = 3 after you've read row 1 to 3, you will never read the row with cid = 5.

I'd go with an adjusted version of your original query, keeping track of the highest cid from each SELECT, and use that value the next time you SELECT 3 more rows.

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE cid > "previous_highest_cid"
ORDER BY `cid` ASC LIMIT 3
```

Will probably be faster, you won't miss any rows etc.